# Recommended document size? (Many small documents vs. Fewer large documents)

Tags: pouchdb

Let's assume that I want to store some statistics every day about how the user is using the application. The user is supposed to be able to look at these statistics for daily, weekly, monthly and also yearly usage.

Would you suggest creating a new document in the database every day with an `_id` of `stats + localeDateString` or creating a single document called `stats`, which is basically a nested object and stores the different years, months, dates?

The downside I see with creating just one document is that it could become quite large over time and turn into an expensive read / write / sync operation.

Contrarily, if I create a new document for every day, I will end up with hundreds of documents. So if the user wants to see his stats for a full year, I need to retrieve 365 documents from the database and merge them. This also doesn't sound so great.

Would you suggest using fewer and larger documents or more and smaller documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to store data together that change together. In almost every case, using many, small, unchanging documents is a better idea than a single (or a few) document that gets updated.

This is because in order to update a document you need to first fetch the whole document, parse the json, update the json and then re-upload the whole document, even if a single byte changed. This gets terrible rather quick, and if several process access the document concurrently, the prevalence of update conflicts will increase.

In contrast, the immutable approach is fast, and immune to concurrent update conflicts. So in your case, create a document per day, but use a view to do the aggregation using a reduce.

I wrote this: https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/11/21/Best-and-Worst-Practices.html -- it's for Cloudant, but most of the ideas should also apply to PouchDB.